Python: Diagonalize a matrix of very high dimension?
Currently I am working on a problem which involves diagonalizing a matrix to get the eigen values and eigen vector. But now I want to expand the problem to a dimension of 200,000 x 200,000 in size.
I looked up how I can store the matrix in numpy and someone suggested to use PyTables. It looks promising. But I want to know where there is tool which helps to diagonalize the matrix store in the PyTables.

Is this a sparse matrix? Such matrix would be really HUGE. 150 GiB for float32 and 300 for float64. 2x-4x times this space is required to store the input+output while considering temporary space. Not to mention the amount of computation : AFAIK the best method are at least in O(n**3) (since matrix multiplication has such a complexity in practice). This means 16_000_000_000_000_000 = 16_000 Tera operations so a basic matrix multiplication of such a big matrix will already take at least dozens of minutes on the best available CPUs (the VRAM of GPUs cannot hold such a big matrix).

In addition to the question about whether the matrix is sparse, do you really need all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors or just some? If it's sparse and you need only some, use scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs. If not sparse and you can't store the whole matrix in memory at once, you can represent it as a scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator, using PyTables to manage the memory under the hood.
